# How to set an element's position to be fixed to an parent

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-position

[image]

I'm trying to make the home header element to be fixed in position even it scrolled. But I want the header element to be fixed inside that part of the width. I mean in the middle part alone. But it's going through the right part as it's window width. You can see it by checking the border bottom of the element. How to make to fit inside the middle home part itself ?

This is the middle part's code

```
<div className="flex flex-col relative">
      <h1 className="p-3 font-semibold flex flex-row justify-between items-center border-b backdrop-blur-sm fixed w-full top-0">
        Home{" "}
        <span>
          <Sparkle className="text-primary" />
        </span>
      </h1>
      {/* tweet Body */}
      <div className="py-4 mt-10">
        <TweetHeader
          profile={profile}
          tweetText={tweetText}
          tweetImg={tweetImg}
          customSetValue={customSetValue}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
        {/* Tweets */}
        {tweets.map((tweet) => {
          return <Tweets key={tweet.id} tweet={tweet} likeTweet={likeTweet} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

The h1 element is the home header. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `fixed`, try using `sticky` class on heading element. Fixed elements are positioned relative to the viewport. `sticky` class will position it relative to its nearest scrolling container. Here's a small example on how you can create that.

```html
<div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl grid grid-cols-[.4fr_1fr_.4fr] items-start justify-items-center">
  <div class="sticky inset-0 bg-red-500 w-full h-36">
    Navbar
  </div>

  <main class="w-full max-w-2xl px-4">
    <header class="sticky inset-0 w-full px-2 py-4 bg-green-600/60">
      Home
    </header>

    <div class="space-y-4">
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
      <div class="h-32 bg-blue-500"></div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div class="sticky inset-0 bg-yellow-500 w-full h-36">
    Sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

With the `sticky` class on `header`, it will fit inside its container, which will not be possible with `fixed` class. You can use this snippet as a reference on how you can create the rest of the layout and components.

Comment: But I'm trying to make the header to be fixed and when I scroll, The header should be stay still and the elements below it should scroll behind the header.

Comment: Yes that can be done using sticky class. `sticky` will make the header stick to its nearest parent that has scrolling mechanism. Since I don't know how you have created the rest of the layout I've created a small [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/73NXAf3BBg) on how you can achieve that. Notice how the header fit inside its container.

Comment: I've also edited my answer and pasted the code above in case the link doesn't work.